# How to use featured image in Previous/Next navigation on single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using twenty fifteen theme in wordpress. I want to add featured image in post navigation of single.php

For navigation code is

```
the_post_navigation( array(
      'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Next', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
          '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
          '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
      'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
          '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
          '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
  ) );
```

How can i add image in this code ?

Comment: better to post this q in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Get the next and previous post IDs using the Wordpress functions *[get_next_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post)* and *[get_previous_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post)*. Then you can use *[get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)*. Like so:

```
    // Previous/next post navigation.
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    $previous_post = get_previous_post();
    the_post_navigation( array(
        'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Next', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
            '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
            '<span class="post-title">%title</span>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($next_post->ID,'thumbnail'),
        'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Previous', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
            '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous post:', 'twentyfifteen' ) . '</span> ' .
            '<span class="post-title">%title</span>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($previous_post->ID,'thumbnail'),
    ) );
```